# Three Diophantine equations in three variables, finding $x+y+z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

We have 3 equations:
$$9x+y-8z=0$$
$$4x-8y+7z=0$$ 
$$xy+yz+zx=47$$
$x, y$ and $z$ are positive integers; we have to find their sum.

I am not sure if the question is correct because I have not been able to solve it.

Comment: can you solve this system of equations?

Comment: I did try that and had got an answer where x = sqrt(8.93). But I don't think it is right as the question says it should be a positive integer.

Comment: Solve the first two equations for $x,y$ to express them in terms of $z$

Comment: I did try that and got y = 96x/57 and z = 76x/57

Comment: i found that $$x=3,y=5,z=4$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the first and second equations together:
$$13x-7y-z=0$$
$$z=13x-7y$$
Now substitute back into the first equation to eliminate $z$:
$$9x+y-8(13x-7y)=0$$
$$-95x+57y=0$$
$$3y=5x$$
Since all variables are positive integers and 3 is relatively prime to 5, $y$ must be a multiple of 5 and $x$ a multiple of 3. We can write $x=3k$ and $y=5k$, where $k$ is a positive integer. After substituting these into the last equation to eliminate $x$ and $y$ it becomes
$$15k^2+8kz=47$$
$$k(15k+8z)=47$$
But note that 47 is a prime number, so one of $15k+8z$ and $k$ must be 1. It cannot be $15k+8z$ since the lowest value it can attain is 23, so $k=1$. The solution to the original system of equations then follows easily:
$$x=3,y=5,z=4,x+y+z=12$$
You may verify that all three equations are satisfied by these values.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely had made some mistake. Nice solution, simpler and easier.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: eliminating $y,z$ from the given system we obtain $$x^2=9$$

Comment: I must have made a calculation mistake. I got x^2 = 8.93. Can you just tell me how did you proceed?